# How to do IF logic in HandleBars templates?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

In underscore templates I can do if logic like this:

```
<% if(type === 'video') { %>
    // Something
<% } %>
```

In handlebars can I do something similar? Tried this but it doesn't work:

```
{{#if type === 'video'}}
    // Something
{{/if}}
```

Tried using helpers too but still no luck:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('isVideo', function(type) {
    if(type === 'video') {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});

{{#if isVideo type}}
    // Something
{{/if}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1 === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

You can then call the helper in the template like this

```
 {{#ifCond v1 v2}}
    {{v1}} is equal to {{v2}}
{{else}}
    {{v1}} is not equal to {{v2}}
{{/ifCond}}
```

Comment: Thanks Charlie. You know ur stuff man. That's twice you've answered one of my questions, directly or indirectly.

Answer (score 0):

[From the Handlebars docs](http://handlebarsjs.com/#conditionals):

> You can use the if helper to conditionally render a block. If its argument returns false, undefined, null, "" or [] (a "falsy" value), Handlebars will not render the block.

```
<div class="entry">
  {{#if author}}
  <h1>{{firstName}} {{lastName}}</h1>
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

> when used with an empty ({}) context, will result in:

```
<div class="entry">
</div>
```

You could include something like `videoType` in your context and check that.